# How to encode x264 remotely but build file locally?

Tags: linux, windows, encoding, x264

Eg

1. .avs script created on local Windows machine.
2. Video source is also on local machine.
3. But encoding is done on remote Linux machine? And the new encoded file is not stored on Linux machine, but is sent over/built in the Windows machine.

Is something like that possible? My problem is that I have local Windows machine with enough storage, but not enough resources for CPU encoding and vice versa with the remote Linux machine enough CPU, but no storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible you would have to most probably write a script on the linux machine.

If you use handbrake the watch folder could come in handy.

- Share a folder on the Windows Machine (Storage) and mount it on
  your Linux Machine(Encoder), create two directories within that share.
- Use cron and rsync to monitor the Storage share every X mins and
  copy them to the handbrake watch directory. (Make sure you have set
  handbrake up to encode automatically to your preferred presets)
- Use cron and rsync to monitor the handbrake converted directory every
  x mins and copy it over to the windows completed share folder    and
  delete the files from the handbrake converted folder.

I hope this helps.

It is simple to do but I am assuming you know some basic scripting.